# Searchview con Firebase como base de datos

Tags: android, firebase, searchview

Estoy intentando realizar un searchview con firebase como bd pero no consigo avanzar. Ya mire de todo y nada.

La base de datos en firebase son unos "Games" con un "name", me gustaria hacer un search cuando quiera buscar un "name" en concreto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El mainactivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView mListView;
private FirebaseListAdapter<String> adapter;

private FirebaseDatabase mDatabase;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://fir-listview-bb0ba.firebaseio.com/Games");

    FirebaseListAdapter<String> firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(
            this,
            String.class,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            databaseReference
    ) {


        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, String model, int position) {

            TextView textView = (TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            textView.setText(model);

        }
    };
    mListView.setAdapter(firebaseListAdapter);

    }
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menuSearch);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

            s (newText);
            return false;
        }
    });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

private void s(final String newText) {

    DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mDatabase.child("Games").orderByChild("name").startAt(newText).endAt("~");}}
```